# How to make UI animation in Scene2d?

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I am using a table in libgdx scene2d to group my labels for my score:

```
lblScore = new Label("Score: " + Integer.toString(score), labelStyle);
        lblBscore = new Label("Best: " + Integer.toString(bScore), labelStyle);

        table = new Table();
        table.setFillParent(true);
        table.setDebug(false);

        table.top();
        table.add(lblScore).padTop(Constant.HEIGHT / 2 - 100);
        table.row();
        table.add(lblBscore).padTop(10);
        stage.addActor(table);
```

What I want to happen is that when my character dies the table will show up with an animation, also is it a good idea that while my character is alive the table is just hidden? or should I just create the table when my character dies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify what kind of animation you wanted to do, but check out the Actions class as it has a bunch of actions you can use for animating Scene2d components (move, color change, fade in/out, rotate, etc):

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/Actions.html

And here is a tutorial with example code that demonstrates how to use the Actions:

http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-2-Actions.aspx

Comment: Any kind of animation as long as it shows the table.

Comment: Yes, all of those actions will work on the Table. So you can choose any of those actions and even run several actions together at the same time in parallel (as shown in the game from scratch tutorial) to create more custom animations.

Comment: One last question, how do you trigger to do the action? because once you do //actor.addAction(action) it will automatically do the action on his own.

Comment: The way I do it is I keep a global reference to the action and reuse it. In the method where you start the action on the table, first reset the action with action.reset() and then add the action to the table.